# Книга с описанием

Tags: java, книги

Подскажите книгу, где описываются библиотеки Java(классы и методы в них) а русском.

Answer (score 2):

Частично в Хорстманне это можно найти. Книга называется Java 2, в двух томах. Там самое основное и частоиспользуемое. Но лучше всё таки читать документацию на английском и переводить.

Comment: два тома Хорстмана прочитать пару раз! к шилду даже не прикосаться.

Comment: А чем Шилдт плох, если не секрет? Просто сам изучаю по Хорстманну и документации, а Шилда хотел как раз после Хорстманна проштудировать.

Answer (score 1):

учите язык так как на русском языке книги как правило к моменту окончания перевода уже марально устаревшие. только оригинал, только сырцы.

Comment: тогда на английском может скажите

Comment: @Slavka_, Да все тот же Хорстманн. Хотя если интересуют только "классы и методы в них", то должно хватить и [Java Platform API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Comment: Если на английском, то нужно оригинальну документацию от Oracle читать и только ее. На русском справочники не рекомендуется иметь не потому что устаревают, а прежде всего из-за хороших переводчиков на Руси